Can I create private xrpl network without xrp?
I'm a beginner with XRPL. I'm trying to create a completely private network using rippled etc. but without any internal use of XRP currency.
As I (mis?)understand there must be XRP reserves for token creation and also to cover transaction costs on the public ledger, but this is 100% private, no gateways etc.
So is there a path to token creation and transactions in this scenario? Maybe this is an idiot question.
